# How to set the Style of a ListViewItem based on the class of the item

Tags: wpf

I remember, some time ago, seeing an example on MSDN of how you could change the Style of a LitViewItem based on the class type of the object in that item.

Can anyone point me in the direction of this example or one like it? I'm converting a file manager and I'd love to use this approach.

Thanks,
Tom P.

EDIT:
OK, I don't think I described my problem correctly. Let me try code:

```
public class IOItem
{
}

public class FileItem : IOItem
{
}

public class DirectoryItem : IOItem
{
}

public class NetworkItem : IOItem
{
}
```

Now, given the above classes can I create a Style that changes based on the class type of the final object? For example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FileItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DirectoryItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Since the variable that picks which style to use is nothing more than the Type.. of the object, you don't need any form of converter or c# magic, you just simply set a style, within scope, for the Type that you want to change. (see my answer, it's sexy!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `StyleSelector` and assign it to the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` property. In the selector, just pick a style based on the type of the item.

```
class MyStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is FileItem)
            return Application.Current.Resources["FileItemStyle"];
        if (item is DirectoryItem)
            return Application.Current.Resources["DirectoryItemStyle"];
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I swear I saw a XAML-only solution but this was back when XMAL first came around. This works and does exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a template selector.

[DataTemplateSelector Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

Another option would be an interface and one of properties in the interface would reflect the call.
Then you could use templates in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just put the styles for the class types inside the resources collection of the List control that you're using, they'll override any global styles you've set.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
        <ListView.Resources>

          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

           <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>


        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

If you're going to want more than one list control to include those specific class styles then create a style for the list control and include the type specific styles in side it's resources.

```
  <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="myListStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" Style="{StaticResource myListStyle}" />
```