# How to update colors, in place, and save them for use next time?

Tags: wpf, themes, resourcedictionary

OK, I'm ready to accept that I'm doing this wrong but this is what I've come up with so far.

I have a couple of ListViews. They have FileSystemInfo items in them. A style (from a Resource Dictionary) is applied based on the object type of the item (based on [How to set the Style of a ListViewItem based on the class of the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802979/how-to-set-the-style-of-a-listviewitem-based-on-the-class-of-the-item)).

I'd like to give the user the ability to change the color being applied. To that end I'm using the method suggested here (http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html) to reload the ResourceDictionary after editing it (currently, by Notepad++).

This does not cause the ListView items to redraw and the color does not change. I have tried to simply use two Resource xaml files and that does not update the colors in place either.

So, what is best practice for updating the colors of the controls, in place, and then saving that to use next time the user runs the app?

<-- EDIT -->

To be specific, what I did was:

1) I made a Style that used a Color from the ResourceDictionary. Like so:

```
<Color x:Key="DirItemBkgdColor1" />
<Color x:Key="DirItemBkgdColor2" />

<Style x:Key="DirListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DirItemBkgdColor1}" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DirItemBkgdColor2}" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

2) I made settings for each of the colors I wanted to change.
3) I modified the one with the other:

```
this.Resources["DirItemBkgdColor1"] = FileTrackerWPF.Properties.Settings.Default.DirectoryBackColor1;
this.Resources["DirItemBkgdColor2"] = FileTrackerWPF.Properties.Settings.Default.DirectoryBackColor2;
```

I put those lines of code in the OnStartup() for the Application and in the Config window of my app and it works like a charm. Now to expand it by several dozen (it's a heavy UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

1. Make sure all your controls that need the color are getting it from the same dynamic resource.
2. Allow user to pick the color. [Extended WPF toolkit has a color picker](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)
3. Save the color in a [settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) that is specific to the user.
4. [Override the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403606/how-to-change-resource-dictionary-color-in-the-runtime) with the saved setting when they pick a color and on application load.

Comment: So the ResourceDictionary would load it's colors from the Settings? No need to externalize the RD. I'll see if this is what I mean. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, it may be easier for the user this way.

Comment: Thanks, after figuring out what I actually wanted to do, this was a big help.

I find the biggest problem I have with WPF is figuring out what I actually want to do in the new XAML context.

Thanks a ton!